# Asking for possible collaboration if unknown and early-stage researcher

Tags: research-process, collaboration, mentoring

I wonder if anyone can help with the following question.

I'm doing research after a different professional experience, so I'm presently in an early stage of my new career - although I'm in my middle age. I would like to establish some sort of connection - possibly collaboration - with a researcher I admire, but who doesn't know me.

How should I address this person in the best way in order to hopefully obtain a positive response? Unfortunately, there are no chances for me to get to know her directly through some kind of congress or conference for the moment.
I hope I shouldn't simply give up the idea...

Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: That depends on your situation. Maybe a colleague can introduce you? Is there a specific project that you have in mind with which you could spark her interest? Generally, researchers are humans. If you approach them with respect and an open mind you are already doing something right.

Comment: In addition: come with concrete (and reasonable) and short proposals. Maybe a project you want her/him to participate. Make clear what you expect from her/his participation. Sometimes there are mentoring programs. This typically aims at particular groups like women and/or people of color. If you fall in such a category then asking her/him to participate in such a program as mentor might be an option.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see your answers go in the same direction and I'll take good note of your advice.